# Example to construct a vector space adding further structure and constraints from coordinate space?

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

From wikipedia it says about [coordinate space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_space)

> By adding further structure and constraints, a coordinate space may be used to construct an object such as a vector space or a manifold.

I have not found anywhere how to construct a vector space $V$ starting from a coordinate space.    
 Can you provide me an example about this construction ? Cartesian coordinate system should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a coordinate space, you naturally have a set of the form $S=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n C_i$. In order to extend this set to a vector space all you need is to choose an underlying $\textit{field}$, $\mathbb{F}$ for the vector space and define the maps

$$ +: S \times S \to S $$
$$ .: S \times \mathbb{F} \to S $$

such that $(S,+)$ forms an additive abelian group and $.$ is distributive over scalar addition and field addition, existence of scalar inverse.

A simple example would be to look at $S= \mathbb{R}^n$ and choose $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$. For any elements,

$$x=(x_1,x_2,\dots.x_n)$$
$$y=(y_1,y_2,\dots.y_n)$$

in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ simply define,

$$x+y= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i)$$ 
$$\alpha x=(\alpha x_1, \alpha x_2, \dots, \alpha x_n)$$.

Then you can easily verify that the above choice satisfies the condition for a vector space.

Comment: mm.. very interesting, just a thing: underlying $\textit{field}$ $\mathbb{F}$ seems to works like a *plane* - in this context, is there some connection between these algebraic structures - *Field* and *Plane* - which vector space is builded ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "seems to work like a plane" and hence I don't answer your question. Fields are just sets with two algebraic operations. Henceforth for a set to be a vector space ,  two operations and a field has to be chosen such that they are compatible.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding: in this context, it seems to me that the field behavior remember me like a kind of *reflection transformation on an affine space*. In this context, field remember me a special 'mirror' because it 'reflects' the coordinate space in another coordinate space but with different function: vector space $V$. 
This field 'behavior' has suggested some similarities to me in other mathematical relations: it remember me some kind of isometry, but not a real reflection, I was trying to figure out if it was possible to link the hyperplane function to the field operations,

Comment: I notice some affinity, or at least it suggests to me that there is something similar.
So I had thought about the field like a kind of isometry/topology of plane.
Do not worry, I'm doing a semantic transposition in order to visualize the same objects from different points of view because some mathematical relations, inserted in certain contexts, seem to perform the task of other mathematical relations (they *reflect* this function), so I seem to see some equivalences .